# Saving images and other information from facebook and twitter

Tags: c#, facebook, twitter

We are going to do a small campaign on our website. So, basically a user will be asked to authorize through Facebook or Twitter and once they provide permissions, we will save their name and username to a database table and the image to the server.

My question is, it is not illegal or anything to save images and basic information like name, username of the users, right? If nothing wrong, security wise, is it a bad idea to save images to local server? what is the best way to do it in C#?

Comment: Why save names and images when you can just save the user ID and then use the Graph API to get name / current profile image?

Comment: thanks, will look into that. I wanted to have a common table for both twitter and facebook images and information. Graph API is for facebook right? So, for twitter atleast I should save the names and images...

Comment: for twitter you can save the screen name and get back the results, check here https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup

Comment: awesome, thanks again. It is ok to use the images and names on our website, right?

Comment: as long as you have user's authorisation I think you're okay, there are so many 3rd party apps that get user's consent and display data!

Comment: Consent on facebook apps is like consenting to a colonoscopy. You learn too late what it involves exactly...